# Laravel Mix: Update a Node.js dependency

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I am trying to compile webpack configuration files with Laravel Mix.

Following webpack episode on Laracasts Vue 2 series,

```
// Scripts

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
....

// mix
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

When I run $ npm run dev, I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.

// Running

npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm v2.15.5

// The error points to
let extractPlugin = new plugins.ExtractTextPlugin(
/Users/User/Code/project/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:126
```

The issue seems to be update a Node.js dependency: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/264

How do I update the Node.js dependency?

I am trying:

```
$ brew upgrade node : Error = node not installed
$ node -v = 2.15.5
$ npm -v = 4.4.5
$ brew install node // installs but throws error

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/node
...

**$ brew upgrade node // says node 7.5.0 already installed**
$ npm run dev // same error
$ node -v = 4.4.5
```

I also ran $ brew install node which installed, but I got an error:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully. 
>   The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local. 
>   Could not symlink bin/node. 
>   Target /usr/local/bin/node 
>   already exists. You may want to remove it: 
>   `rm '/usr/local/bin/node'`

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

Comment: Tried a `brew upgrade node` ?

Comment: Yeah mentioned that just at the end, getting node not installed but if I run node -v I get 4.4.5

Comment: try `brew unlink node --force && brew uninstall node` - then try installing it again, can try `brew install node@6`

Comment: Installed from nodejs.org source, npm now 4.1.2 and node is 7.5.0

$ npm run dev = new error 

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'

$npm install autoprefixer

Comment: 1 year later I have this on OSX: `$ brew upgrade node Error: node 9.11.1 already installed -- $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.11.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Why is operating not permitted? Try running sudo, or sudo su. Are you on mac os or linux?

Comment: Also, those commands seem like overkill. Can you not update from the command line as my instructions? I got it working eventually.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I installed Node.js again from nodejs.org, rewriting old files.

However this actually downgraded npm from 4.4.5 to 4.1.2... Node.js was 2.15.5 and is now 7.5.0.

I also had to install a few modules: `$ npm install autoprefixer`

```
$ npm run dev // works now
```

Comment: how did you do that?... could you explain more , I had the same problem and i did not find any solution uptill now .

Comment: Had to update node and npm and then there was a bunch of missing dependencies such as autoprefixer...it told me everyone one to download that was missing just a matter of npm install missingdependency there was only 2-3 as far as I can remebmer. Did you get it?

Comment: You should be able to just run `npm install` and it will install all the missing dependencies in your `package.json` file

Answer (score 2):

you can delete your node modules folder in your laravel project.

after that run :

```
npm install - g npm
```

this command will reinstall the node modules folder with upgrading node files.
next, you can try and run

```
npm run dev
```

and you can also run

```
npm update
```

to update your node

hope this answer will help

Answer (score 0):

Im Using Windows 10
You can Download NVM for node it stands for node version manager
after you set it up, type this to your cmd

```
nvm version
nvm install node {version of node you want}
nvm use {version of node}
```

hope this works for you 
because it works for me